# Spring multiple path variables between 2 slashes

Tags: spring, rest, api, path-variables

I'm developing an API and the requirement says something like this:

```
localities/{x},{y}/
```

The question is: Can I code this with spring? It is a correct way to use path variables?

I thought I'd do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/localities/{x},{y}/")
```

but I don't know if it's gonna work.

Comment: Based on documentation of `@RequestMapping` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#path--) it supports Ant style, so it should work

Comment: _"I don't know if it's gonna work"_ Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: @cassiomolin I was leaving work haha

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

@RequestMapping("/localities/{x}/{y}")
public yourMethod(@PathVariable(value="x") int num1, @PathVariable(value="y") int num2){

}

Answer (score 0):

Your url is supposed to be '/localities/{x}/{y}

Something like this should work

```
@RequestMapping("/localities/{x}/{y}")
public String localities(@PathVariable long x, @PathVariable long y) {
    // ...
}
```